# I want remove last after wp_nav_menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

This is my file:

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
'theme_location'  => '',
'menu'            => '',
'container'       => 'div',
'container_class' => true,
'container_id'    => 'btn',
'menu_class'      => true,
'menu_id'         => '',
'echo'            => true,
'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
'before'          => '',
'after'           => '<li class="btn_bar"><img src="img/pic-btn_bar.jpg"/></li>',
'link_before'     => '',
'link_after'      => '',
'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
'depth'           => 0,
'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>
```

Here, I insert class="btn_bar">

```
<ul>
<li class="menu-item-xxx">ABC</li>
<li class="btn_bar"><img width="18" height="38" src="img/pic-btn_bar.jpg"></li>
<li class="menu-item-xxx">DEF</li>
<li class="btn_bar"><img width="18" height="38" src="img/pic-btn_bar.jpg"></li>
</ul>
```

I want to put the code in the menu  first or last menu. Please help me

Comment: i have add youe image code after first and last menu using js so use this one code define below thnks.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you could just do this with CSS instead of PHP/HTML. With CSS you could target a specific menu item and use pseudo after to insert an image.

```
.menu-item-82:after {  
content: " ";    
position: relative;
background: url(images/nav-image.png) -1px -32px #ddd;  
display: block;  
height: 25px;  
width: 25px;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another simple css hack, aslong as you have determined your menu item id

```
#menu-item-1244 .delimiter {display:none;}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            jQuery("#doctype li:first").after("<li class='btn_bar'><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNk7r.jpg?s=24&g=1'/></li>");
            jQuery("#doctype li:last").after("<li class='btn_bar'><img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNk7r.jpg?s=24&g=1'/></li>");
        });
</script>    

<?php
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => 'primary',
    'menu'            => 'Menu 1',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => '',
    'container_id'    => 'doctype',
    'menu_class'      => '',
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul class="filter">%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );
?>
```

[image]